# How to know what packages/modules you need to import in Python code

Tags: python, package, python-import

How do you know which python modules/packages you need to import in the beginning of your code?

Comment: You need to import whichever ones you use, if any.

Comment: I usually import the modules that I plan to use.

Comment: If you use a name that isn't either built-in or locally defined, then it has to be imported from somewhere.

Comment: Usually, you know this by reading documentation for the functions you want to use.

Comment: When your first learning, you probably won't know what to import till you run into a problem you can't solve then you go looking through the tutorial and documentation and hopefully find something that will help you then you add that to your imports and after a while you'll have a feel for what you might need before you start but it seems every once and a while you still need more help and then you go find another module/package.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want your code to do.

Modules are usually just collections of functions that do different things.  For example, the module "random" contains functions for generating random numbers; and "colored" lets you change the font and background of the text you print in your terminal.

You can look around on sites like github.com to find cool libraries that may help you, or you may simply google around.